# In Desmos, function fills entire screen unless $y$ is used in some denominator

Tags: graphing-functions, desmos

In Desmos, I am graphing the equation
$$(g^2 - 4x)y^2 + (2g - 4x - 4)y + 1 = 0$$
which uses the helper function
$$g = x + 1 - \frac{x^2 - 2x + 1}{x + 1 + 2\sqrt x}$$

which fills up the entire screen, even though it should be a smooth curve. Strangely, when I add $y$ in any denominator of the main function, say setting the function equal to $0/y$ instead of $0$, the function works just fine and is displayed correctly.

**Buggy Curve:**
[image: Buggy Curve]

**Intended Curve:**
[image: Intended Curve]

I would think that having $y$ in the denominator like this would change things when $y=0$, but without it, the whole screen is filled up (every $y$ value.) I can't figure out the reason that this might be.

---

Here are the equation sources to paste into desmos:

> Helper Function: `g=x+1-\frac{x^{2}-2x+1}{x+1+2\sqrt{x}}`
>
> Buggy Equation: `\left(g^{2}-4x\right)\cdot y^{2}+\left(2g-4x-4\right)\cdot y+1=0`
>
> Fixed Equation: `\left(g^{2}-4x\right)\cdot y^{2}+\left(2g-4x-4\right)\cdot y+1=\frac{0}{y}`

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: If you think this is a bug in Desmos, and it seems you can demonstrate that, then you're on the wrong site.  This is not Desmos-support :)

Comment: Maybe you should reframe the question as mainly asking if your math is sensible (e.g. is the implicit function really the same upon dividing with $y$?), making the possible Desmo bug a secondary concern. Otherwise this question is likely to be closed via community votes or just be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite some redundancy in the way your implicit function was formulated. Note that the rational function in $g$ can be simplified.
$$
\frac{x^2 - 2x + 1}{x + 1 + 2\sqrt x}= \left(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x} + 1} \right)^2 = \left(\frac{(\sqrt{x} + 1)(\sqrt{x} - 1)}{\sqrt{x} + 1} \right)^2 = (\sqrt{x} - 1)^2
$$
Put this back into $g$ we have
$$g=x+1-(x-2\sqrt{x} + 1) = 2 \sqrt{x}$$
The curve $(g^2 - 4x)y^2 + (2g - 4x - 4)y + 1 = 0$ therefore goes from an implicit function to an explicit function.
$$\begin{align}
&\implies 0 \cdot y^2 +(4\sqrt{x}-4x-4)y+1=0 \\
&\implies y = \frac14 \frac1{x-\sqrt{x}+1}
\end{align}$$